# LoadError when trying to run server and create new rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting this error when trying to run server or create new rails app.

```
/usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rails-4.2.1/bin/rails (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
```

Rails was working fine after I cloned two projects I was trying to recreate. I installed the necessary gems for it. Since then I'm not able to run server.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE AND SOLUTION:
I had cloned an old project that must've used old gem versions. I had to update gems and had to overwrite railties to be able to start server normally (without using bundle exec rails s).

thanks

Comment: Did you run bundle before running rails server?

Comment: After cloning you should run `bundle install`. Have you done that?